# SQL Server - How to remove IsPersisted attribute on computed column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

In SQL Server, how can we switch off the PERSISTED attribute of a computed column using T-SQL? I am able to do this using Management Studio GUI but do not know how to do it using T-SQL.

Comment: You can generate the actual script used by the GUI by clicking on the "Script" button instead of Save. You can't alter a PERSISTED column, though, you can only drop it and recreate it. The GUI either does that or actually drops and rebuilds the entire table

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to *drop* the `PERSISTED` property from your column, then you can try the following:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTable ALTER COLUMN MyColumn DROP PERSISTED;
```

According to [**MSDN**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx):

> [ {ADD | DROP} PERSISTED ]
>
> ```
> Specifies that the PERSISTED property is added to or dropped 
> from the specified column. The column must be a computed column that is
> defined with a deterministic expression.
> ```

**Related:** You can also have a look at [**this**](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3338/change-all-computed-columns-to-persisted-in-sql-server/) article by Aaron Bertrand.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by following this steps:

1. Create a new column in your table having the same datatype as that of your persisted column.
2. Update the new column with the persisted column value.
3. Remove the persisted column from your table.
4. Rename the new column as that of the persisted column.

Comment: This quote is about a different thing, whether statistics are available while the DDL executes. You can't alter a persisted column at all.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos:- Yes got that. Removed that!